# Is it possible to create a Custom FileDialog in SWT/RCP

Tags: swing, swt, rcp, jfilechooser, filedialog

The existing FileDialog opens once we call the FileDialog constructor is -
[image]

Now I want to customize the same.
For example I want to add a new Button after Cancel named "Append".
Can it be possible in plain java ?
Also solution in Swing will work , then will use bridge to incorporate.

Comment: The native FileDialog cannot be customized in this way. You can only the define the button 'open' with style bit `SWT.OPEN` and the button save with style bit `SWT.SAVE`.If you like to create new buttons and other functionality you have to build your own dialog. Probably the best way to do this is to create a new dialog shell. [Example here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DialogShell.htm).